# CSS - Can't override style for WordPress' 'Continue Reading' text

Tags: css, wordpress

Normally I'm pretty competent with CSS but I just can't figure this one out...

[Here](http://catpr.com/craig-chapman/?page_id=16) is a subdomain for a site I'm creating...

The 'Read More' part of it, no matter how I try to override the CSS and remove the text-decoration: underline; , it will not remove.

The only way I've managed to remove it is via applying a universal a:link { text-decoration: none; }, but I really don't want to do that, I just want to remove only the 'Read More' Underline.

Can anybody save my from my CSS insanity?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what you're tried. In your style.css file you have `p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
 }` so where have you tried to override this?

Comment: Could you expand that short URL, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the underline from all links in the post snippet, try to add a class to the "read more" link. Currently the span within the link has a class, but for this purpose that doesn't help you much.

It would look something like this:

```
<a class="read_more" href="http://catpr.com/craig-chapman/?p=1"><span class="pictos read-more">Read More</span></a>
```

And the CSS:

```
a.read_more {text-decoration:none}
```

Because you're working in WordPress, you'd need to edit the theme files to do so (give the link a class, that is).

If you don't care about removing the underline from all of the links in the snippet, the other answers provided will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Jordan - the problem was that I was targeting a span within an anchor, I've looked this up and apparently it's valid markup, but for whatever reason putting a class on the anchor finally enabled me to get rid of the underline

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do this ?

```
.entry-content p a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a style in your stylesheet that says:

```
p a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You are having trouble overriding it because of the 'p' making the selector more specific. Use the following to override:

```
.entry-content p a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```